# Reducing the size of index files

Tags: java, lucene

Okay after having so much doubts in `lucene indexing`, I tried a program to index every files in a folder and able to index 76 files of 131 MB which includes mostly ppt, pdf and docs. The index file size is around 80 MB.It did it in 36 seconds and searched a query in 7 milli seconds.

- Is it faster?
- Is the size of the index file is normal?
- Any way to reduce the size of indexing?
- Every time I have to run the indexer program whenever I add a new
  file. Is there any automatic way to do the indexing whenever new file
  is adder?

Here is my indexer file which is actually from `Lucene` *In Action* book

```
package lia.meetlucene;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
public class Indexer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: java " + Indexer.class.getName()
        + " <index dir> <data dir>");
    }
    String indexDir = args[0];         //1
    String dataDir =  args[1];          //2

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Indexer indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
    int numIndexed;
    try {
      numIndexed = indexer.index(dataDir);
    } finally {
      indexer.close();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Indexing " + numIndexed + " files took "
      + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
  }

  private IndexWriter writer;

  public Indexer(String indexDir) throws IOException {
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
    writer = new IndexWriter(dir,            //3
                 new StandardAnalyzer(       //3
                     Version.LUCENE_30),//3
                 true,                       //3
                             IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED); //3
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    writer.close();                             //4
  }

  public int index(String dataDir)
    throws Exception {
try{
    File[] files = new File(dataDir).listFiles();

    for (File f: files) {
        if(f.isDirectory())
        {
            index(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
       else if (!f.isDirectory() &&
          !f.isHidden() &&
          f.exists() &&
          f.canRead()
          ) {
        indexFile(f);
      }
    }
}
      catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return writer.numDocs();                     //5
  }


  protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f)));      //7
    doc.add(new Field("filename", f.getName(),              //8
                Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));//8
    doc.add(new Field("fullpath", f.getCanonicalPath(),     //9
                Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));//9
    return doc;
  }

  private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Indexing " + f.getCanonicalPath());
    Document doc = getDocument(f);
    writer.addDocument(doc);                              //10
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple of comments about your code:

1. `doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f)));      //7`
   Are you sure this is right? If your files are binaries (ppt, pdf...) you are indexing the raw bytes here, you should look at a text extraction tool like [tika](https://tika.apache.org/%E2%80%8E)
   That would decrease the size of you index greatly.
2. Also verify your index is using [compound file format](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/fileformats.html), this would make it smaller.

Comment: Actually the original code is written to index text files. I removed the filters to index every file formats. Is it wrong to do like this?

Comment: yes it's wrong, you are using the actual bytes that are the pdf file, not the *text contents* of it, you need to extract the text.

Comment: Does tika requires xml files to index files?

Comment: [Tika is a content analysis toolkit](https://tika.apache.org/).  It doesn't index anything.  You would use it to extract the text, which would then be indexed by lucene.

Comment: @femtoRgon where can I find a example program for Tika

Comment: @user3275057 When I google "tika example", the 10 top results each provide code and an explanation of what it does.